# How to export AWS Glue Crawler schema in a text-human-readable format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

AWS Glue Crawler is a powerful tool to infer schema from large data source but I find it quite challenging to share the inferred schema with colleagues, in particular when the schema is relatively complex.

Is there any easy way to export it in a Spark fashion for example? (namely `printSchema()` method)